# How to raise an event when datagrid has changed

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

This one is not really a problem but more like a possibility i am exploring. 
I have got 2 datagrids on two different wpf windows. the windows have a prev and next button,to navigate between the datagrid 1 and 2. the content of the second datagrid depends on what you choose in the first one,and each datagrid has its own db table,with a one to many relation between the two.
I want to raise an event when the user changes anything in the first datagrid, so that i can do stuff in the second. i tried to use

```
TargetUpdated="datagrid_targetupdated"
```

and

```
NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True
```

but since the datagrid gets populated on loading, the event just triggers at the beginning,which makes it kinda useless.
I could raise a propertyChanged event for each control,but wouldnt it be the same on loading?

Comment: First load the `ItemsSource` into `Datagrid` then attach the event.  Will it work?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using the RowEditEnding event for the DataGrid to change the second grid. You can find more information about it online.

Answer (score 0):

I've found theres a method called CellEditEnding that does what i need. Probably RowEditEnding does the same, but i just read your comment and i didnt test it out

```
DataGridassemble.CellEditEnding += datagrid_targetupdated;
private void datagrid_targetupdated(object sender,DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e ){
        // do whatevs    
}
```

i can add the property in the code or in the xaml,with same result